# Blank Rows On Specialized Import

Tags: vba, excel

I have data that's coming in every day. This is the script I've patched together to append it to the first blank cell in the set. When I run it, the script correctly pastes it in blank cells, but there are several hundred, maybe thousand blank rows in between.

```
'Sub Read_CSV_Files()
Dim sPath As String
Dim oPath, oFile, oFSO As Object
Dim r, iRow As Long
Dim wbImportFile As Workbook
Dim wsDestination As Worksheet

'Files location
sPath = 'insert path here.
Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data")

r = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Offset(1, 0).Row
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oPath = oFSO.GetFolder(sPath)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each oFile In oPath.Files
    If LCase(Right(oFile.Name, 4)) = ".csv" Then
        'open file to import
        Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=oFile.Path, Origin:=65001, StartRow:=2, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Comma:=True, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        Set wbImportFile = ActiveWorkbook
        For iRow = 1 To wbImportFile.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
             wbImportFile.Sheets(1).Rows(iRow).Copy wsDestination.Rows(r)
            r = r + 1
        Next iRow
        wbImportFile.Close False
        Set wbImportFile = Nothing
    End If
Next oFile
End Sub
```

I'm still pretty new, this script was cobbled together from another found on this forum. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the problem you describe would most likely relate to the `wbImportFile.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count`; the `.UsedRange` object is notoriously unreliable.  See [here](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/10/02/find-last-row-in-an-excel-sheetvbavb-net/) for a better way of finding the last row in an Excel range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the unreliable nature of `.UsedRange`, I'd recommend changing this part of your code:

```
    For iRow = 1 To wbImportFile.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
         wbImportFile.Sheets(1).Rows(iRow).Copy wsDestination.Rows(r)
        r = r + 1
    Next iRow
```

To this:

```
    For iRow = 1 To wbImportFile.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
         wbImportFile.Sheets(1).Rows(iRow).Copy
         r = wsDestination.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
         wsDestination.Range("A" & r).PasteSpecial
    Next iRow
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much. I realize the rules inhibit semi-off topic discussion, but I'd love to know what resources you used to learn so much.